# Process CSV with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I'm trying to process a CSV with [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get("file.csv", function(data) {
        array = jQuery.csv()(data);
    });
});
```

But all I get is this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.csv is not a function

The paths are definitely right.
Also I can see the csv with just `console.log(data)`.

Has anybody any experience with jquery-csv?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv#usage, try this:

```
array = jQuery.csv.toArray(data);
```